# unable to set preferences for Firefox profile with Selenium (geckodriver 0.16)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Just installed geckodriver 0.16.1 and updated firefox to 53 (64bit) and my script appears like it is not setting preferences. Here is the code I use set Firefox profile so it automatically downloads a ms word file without the download prompt.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/msword")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

This script worked before updating Firefox and geckodriver. Now when I run it, the download prompt appears.

Anyone having similar issues or know what changed with geckodriver?

Comment: Hi mark. I have similar issue.. I tried to search browser.download.lastDir. But didn't find anything. I have Firefox 53.0.2.  Can you please share your code? I have similar lines as you gave above plus following lines - profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false); profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false); profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete",false);profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These preferences have changed in newer firefox versions. Go to `about:config` in firefox and search for `browser.download`, it will show you what the newer ones are. For instance, `browser.download.dir` would now be `browser.download.lastDir`

Comment: Hi mark. I have similar issue.. I tried to search browser.download.lastDir. But didn't find anything. I have Firefox 53.0.2.  Can you please share your code?