# Not able set profile preferences for Firefox using Selenium(3.4.0) and geckodriver 0.16

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I recently upgraded to FireFox 53.0.3, Gecko driver 0.16.1 and Selenium 3.4.0. My code below was working fine before this upgrade. After upgrade I get error when I try to set profile preferences. Can someone please tell me what can be the alternative for this or where can I find alternatives for this? I did read existing question - [unable to set preferences for Firefox profile with Selenium (geckodriver 0.16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690353/unable-to-set-preferences-for-firefox-profile-with-selenium-geckodriver-0-16) but I am stuck at what are the replacements for these in Geckodrive.

```
profile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Firefox");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
        "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
        "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer because I spent lot of time to figure out this issue. I tried using FirefoxOptions class and it worked for me. When browser opened, I checked preferences in about:config page and setting were done properly.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\download");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
options.setProfile(profile);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println("Title====" + driver.getTitle());
```